# Getting a row whos value is between 2 columns

Tags: sql, cassandra

**Question:**

Essentially i want to execute the equivalent of SELECT LocID FROM GEOIPMAP where 20 BETWEEN RangeStart AND RangeEnd in Cassandra.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is there a better solution?

**Background:**

We are trying to find a fast, big data solution for a very large table we have. We are considering moving to Cassandra, but I want to know if it is possible to quickly/reasonably get a value which is between two bins( or a better solution, please suggest)

We have a list of ip ranges(int64) that can be joined to another table in sql. The table essentially is:

```
+------------+----------+-------+
| RangeStart | RangeEnd | LocID |
+------------+----------+-------+
|          0 |     5000 |     2 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Some more information about your domain constraints would be helpful. For a given ip, could it be in multiple ranges, or are ranges non-overlapping and there is a many to one mapping between IPs and ranges?

Comment: @TupshinHarper both range start and range end are unique, and never overlap, and there should never be a deadzone. Ranges to location id is a one to many... ranges only have one locID but a single LocID can be found in many different Ranges. Range end maxes out a little over 4 billion.

Answer (score 0):

If your ranges don't overlap you can do this within a partition.

```
CREATE TABLE locs (
  bucket INT,
  rangeend INT,
  locid INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (bucket, rangeend));
```

You will want to use some kind of partition key (bucket) to split things up into multiple partitions, otherwise you will just be making a hotspot on the node that owns this row.

You can then:

```
SELECT locid FROM locs WHERE bucket = 0 AND rangeend > 20 LIMIT 1;
```

Will give you the locid from the first row in partition 0 where range end > 20.